# no output from console.log inside socket.on()

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cloud9

For a school assignment I have to modify the example chat app that's opened when a new Node.js workspace is created on cloud9.io. As I was looking through the code trying to figure out what's happening and what I need to change, I tried putting in some console.logs to see what is happening when, but for some reason most of the console.logs are never printed in the console when I run the app. So I am trying to understand this code and need some help!

One example where console.log is not being printed:
from the index.html

```
<script>
  function ChatController($scope) {
    var socket = io.connect();

    // ...
    // some more $scope.on function

    $scope.send = function send() {
      console.log('Sending message:', $scope.text); // this one gets printed
      socket.emit('message', $scope.text);
      $scope.text = '';
    };
  }
</script>
```

from the server.js

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    messages.forEach(function (data) {
      socket.emit('message', data);
    });

    // this is the code that i don't get. I thought if I send a message, 
    // the socket.emit('message', $scope.text) would call this 
    // socket.on('message' ...) to send the msg, but the text in 
    // console.log is never printed in the console
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
      console.log("sending a message?"); // does not get printed

      var text = String(msg || '');

      if (!text)
        return;

      socket.get('name', function (err, name) {
        var data = {
          name: name,
          text: text
        };

        broadcast('message', data);
        messages.push(data);
      });
    });
  });
```

So yea, if you guys could guide me through this a little bit, that would be great! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different places where `console.log` will go. For your `index.html` file, they will go to the browser console and for your `server.js` file they'll go to the terminal where you're running the app in Cloud9. Check those locations for the specific log you're looking for and you should find them!

Comment: Sorry for a late comment. I figured it out a little after I posted and completely forgot about the post. But yep, this was exactly what happened :)

Comment: Do you need to edit any node env settings or anything else to see `console.log()` from the `server.js` in the terminal? Because I still have the issue of only seeing the front end logs. The terminal does not show anything logs from inside the `io.on('connection', ...` nor anything in all the `socket.on()` inside it. I can only see logs outside the `io.on('connection', ...` in my server.js.